# Oracle Sql groupBy on 2 columns seperately

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have my table as below. I want to group each caseName by zone.

case_status DB

```
caseName    caseBy  id  zone    Cases   Prepped %Complete
ABC         10     0001 Above   1       1        100%
BCD         11     0002 Above   2       1        50%
ABC         10     0001 In      1       1        100%
ABC         10     0001 Below   0       0        0
BCD         11     0002 Below   0       0        0
CEF         12     0003 Above   3       3        100%
CEF         12     0003 In      0       0        0
CEF         12     0003 Below   1       1        100%
BCD         11     0002 In      2       2        100%
CEF         13     0003 Above   3       3        100%
CEF         13     0003 In      0       0        0
CEF         13     0003 Below   1       1        100%
```

My output in UI should look like below. So my sql should return a resultSet like this.

```
    caseName    caseBy  zone    Cases   Prepped %Complete
     ABC        10      Above   1        1      100%
                        In      1        1      100%
                        Below   
                        -----------------------------
                                1         1     100%

    BCD          11    Above    2         1     50%
                       In       2         2     100%
                       Below    
                       ----------------------------
                                 4         3    150%

    CEF          12     Above    3         3    100%
                        In              
                        Below    1         1    100%
                        ----------------------------
                                 4         4    100%

    CEF          13     Above    3         3    100%
                        In              
                        Below    1         1    100%
                                ----------------------------
                                 4         4    100%
```

How do I use gorupBy on caseName and then CaseBy? CEF has 2 cases one for 12 & 13 which should be seperated as above

Comment: It isn't very clear, are you looking for the "Total" rows under the lines ---- ? Also, 3/4 != 150%

Comment: Sorry about that math. Its just an example. My question is how to group by CaseName and then display totals after each Case

Comment: SQL is not the right tool for formatting in a certain layout. Just get the data, possibly the (sub)totals and have the formatting done by a programming language.

Comment: @trincot I agree I can do totals in the UI. How can I do groupBy on 2 fields one wth caseName and the other with caseBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rollup` syntax, which seems exactly fit for your case. You only need to add `rollup()` in the `group by` clause:

```
select   caseName, 
         caseBy, 
         zone, 
         sum(cases) cases, 
         sum(prepped) prepped, 
         case sum(cases) 
             when 0 then 0 
             else 100 * sum(prepped) / sum(cases) 
         end complete 
from     case_status
group by rollup(caseName, caseBy, zone);
```

NB: your own calculation is off: 3 / 4 is not 150%, but 75%. See the formula the in `select` clause.

This query will generate extra rows with sub totals at all different levels. They can be recognised by the `null` values in the grouped columns:

```
CASENAME | CASEBY | ZONE   | CASES | PREPPED | COMPLETE
---------+--------+--------+-------+---------+---------
ABC      |     10 | In     |     1 |       1 |      100
ABC      |     10 | Above  |     1 |       1 |      100
ABC      |     10 | Below  |     0 |       0 |        0
ABC      |     10 | (null) |     2 |       2 |      100
ABC      | (null) | (null) |     2 |       2 |      100
BCD      |     11 | In     |     2 |       2 |      100
BCD      |     11 | Above  |     2 |       1 |       50
BCD      |     11 | Below  |     0 |       0 |        0
BCD      |     11 | (null) |     4 |       3 |       75
BCD      | (null) | (null) |     4 |       3 |       75
CEF      |     12 | In     |     0 |       0 |        0
CEF      |     12 | Above  |     3 |       3 |      100
CEF      |     12 | Below  |     1 |       1 |      100
CEF      |     12 | (null) |     4 |       4 |      100
CEF      |     13 | In     |     0 |       0 |        0
CEF      |     13 | Above  |     3 |       3 |      100
CEF      |     13 | Below  |     1 |       1 |      100
CEF      |     13 | (null) |     4 |       4 |      100
CEF      | (null) | (null) |     8 |       8 |      100
(null)   | (null) | (null) |    14 |      13 |       92.85
```

This gives you all the data you need for the report. I would then leave it up to the application (which connects to the database) to deal with the layout aspects, such as suppression of repeated values, horizontal lines, ...etc.

Also, it seems a waste to actually store the total percentage in your table, as it is just a calculation on the two other present fields.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to use the analytic function `sum over()`. Keep in mind that in your desired output you are not summing the first result set

```
SQL> set lines 200
SQL> with t as
(
select 'ABC' as casename, '0001' as id, 'Above'  as zone,  1 as cases,    1 as prepped,    100 as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'BCD' as casename, '0002' as id, 'Above'  as zone,  2 as cases,    1 as prepped,    50  as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'ABC' as casename, '0001' as id, 'In'     as zone,  1 as cases,    1 as prepped,    100 as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'ABC' as casename, '0001' as id, 'Below'  as zone,  0 as cases,    0 as prepped,    0    as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'BCD' as casename, '0002' as id, 'Below'  as zone,  0 as cases,    0 as prepped,    0   as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'CEF' as casename, '0003' as id, 'Above'  as zone,  3 as cases,    3 as prepped,    100 as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'CEF' as casename, '0003' as id, 'In'     as zone,  0 as cases,    0 as prepped,    0   as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'CEF' as casename, '0003' as id, 'Below'  as zone,  1 as cases,    1 as prepped,    100 as perc_completed from dual union all
select 'BCD' as casename, '0002' as id, 'In'     as zone,  2 as cases,    2 as prepped,    100 as perc_completed from dual
)
select casename, id, zone, cases, prepped, perc_completed,
sum(cases) over (partition by casename, id) as total_cases ,
sum(prepped) over (partition by casename, id ) as total_prepped ,
sum(perc_completed) over (partition by casename, id ) as total_percentage
from t
 18  order by casename, id, zone;

CAS ID   ZONE       CASES    PREPPED PERC_COMPLETED TOTAL_CASES TOTAL_PREPPED TOTAL_PERCENTAGE
--- ---- ----- ---------- ---------- -------------- ----------- ------------- ----------------
ABC 0001 Above          1          1            100           2             2              200
ABC 0001 Below          0          0              0           2             2              200
ABC 0001 In             1          1            100           2             2              200
BCD 0002 Above          2          1             50           4             3              150
BCD 0002 Below          0          0              0           4             3              150
BCD 0002 In             2          2            100           4             3              150
CEF 0003 Above          3          3            100           4             4              200
CEF 0003 Below          1          1            100           4             4              200
CEF 0003 In             0          0              0           4             4              200

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you. That was helpful. I have another field caseBy. IN that case, would I just do orderBy caseName and groupBy caseBy field?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question, you can easily total the Cases/Prepped values by using the SUM() function.
The Zone column is ignored entirely, as that is the non-distinct value that is preventing you from summing the similar rows.

```
SELECT caseName, id, SUM(Cases), SUM(Prepped), (SUM(Prepped)/SUM(Cases)*100) AS "%Complete"
FROM case_status
GROUP BY caseName, id;
```